# Which things need to care with Rails application cluster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cluster-computing

If I plan to create a Rails application cluster , I think the session share is a problem, and I can save session into memcache or database. I want to know are there something else need to be cared ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague, but you should look into load balancing (haproxy is good), an in-memory data store such as memcached and the database will be mysql.  The web tier scales out horizontally so it's easy to increase processing power as needed.  Please clarify your question for more answers.